# Gluten free options at Bank of America Stadium

Tags: food-and-drink, sport

I’m going to a Carolina Panthers game tomorrow at Bank of America Stadium in Charlotte, NC.  I want to know what food and drinks are available and where to find them.

Do any of the vendors carry gluten free beer, such as Omission or Red Bridge? What about cider?

I’ve heard that there’s a place in section 515 that accommodates people with Celiac disease, but can’t find any specifics on the Internet.

Comment: On such short notice I would contact the stadium directly and ask to be put through or get contact details for the food service people. If they do not usually stock your needs, they can on enough advance notice. 'Tomorrow' seems very short notice for something like this.

Comment: Thanks. This isn’t really about me needing an answer today. It’s about supplying Google with better information. I intend to do a little investigation while I’m there and answer the question myself. :)

Comment: You know it is totally allowed and encouraged  here to answer your own question!

Comment: Back from the game, and as promised, I've answered the question.

Comment: You could probably sneak in some of your own alcohol/food too if needed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got back from the game. I went to guest services and they showed me a list of options, which I've copied here verbatim.

> ### Gluten Free Options in Bank of America Stadium
>
> #### 100, 300, 500 Level Market
>
> - Spinach Salad
> - Caesar Salad
> - Fruit Salad
> - Ancient Grain Salad
> - Gluten Free Sandwich Option
>
> #### Club Level
>
> Bowl Concept (Lower Room / Press Box)
>
> - Gourmet Hot Dogs (No Bun)
> - Ancient Grain Power Bowl
> - Southwestern Bowl (Without Corn)
>
> Panther Burgers
>
> - Burgers (No Bun)
>
> Red Zone / Panthers Den
>
> - Pulled Pork (No Bun)
> - Sliced Brisket (No Bun)
> - Hot Dog (No Bun)

Here's a photo of my $8 sandwich, with turkey, cheese, and a tomato on gluten free bread.

[image]

I saw someone with a can of [Crispin](https://www.crispincider.com/) apple cider, but didn't get a chance to hunt one down for myself.

Comment: What about beverages? I know you can get GF beer in Baltimore, for example...

Comment: They definitely have cider. There might be GF beer, but I didn’t come across any.

Comment: Well if you're in the area and feel like seeing the Ravens, they've got Redbridge and gf soft pretzels at m&t bank stadium. ;)